norm equivalence on finite dimensional vector space without assuming that the field used is $\mathbb{R}$
I'm studying functional analysis and thus I have to go back to fundamental properties.
Among them, a well known property is that, in finite dimensions, all norms on a $\mathbb{K}$ vector space are equivalent. Yet, all proofs I found relied on $\mathbb{K}$ being $\mathbb{R}$ with the assumption that all $\mathbb{K}$ were isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.
Yet, if I'm correct, $\mathbb{K}$ is merely required to be a field and fields have not enough properties to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Am I right and, in this case, what is a more general proof of the equivalence of norms?

Norms are, typically, defined only for real and complex spaces. Depending on the argument(s) you've seen, it's probably not difficult to adapt it to $\Bbb{C}$. If you want norm equivalence for vector spaces over more exotic fields, we'll first need a definition of what a norm means over that field.

@TheoBendit Indeed, I'm now realizing that all the resources I'm reading assume that the field upon which the space is built has a certain norm itself, in order to define absolute homogeneity of the space norm...

@Oersted Exactly. In order to define a norm, we need the field to have an absolute value. Now, there is a generalization of the term "absolute value" to arbitrary fields. (for example, this is important when you study $p$-adic numbers) This generalization indeed allows to define normed spaces over arbitrary fields. And if the absolute value makes the field a locally compact topological space, it can be proved that all norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent, just like over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. (and the proof is very similar)

@Mark another property that is often used in proofs is that on $\mathbb{R}$ compact set  are the closed bounded set. It seems that to have this kind of properties on other field, they must be ordered and have a supremum property (ie for all compact subset, there is a greatest/lowest element within this subset). I'm wondering if adding these is sufficient to generalize common properties of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces...

@Oersted An order is not necessary. (even $\mathbb{C}$ is not an ordered field) We need an absolute value which turns the field into a locally compact topological space. (in which case the closed and bounded sets are indeed compact)

@Mark ah indeed, thanks.

Norms are not usually used over fields other than $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. One of the key properties of a norm is that for all vectors $v$ and scalars $r$, we have $||rv|| = |r| \cdot ||v||$.
So for the reals, $|\cdot |$ is the absolute value and for the complex numbers, $| \cdot |$ is the complex magnitude. On these two fields, the proof of equivalence of norms is possible with only slight differences between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.
For other fields, we don't usually define the idea of a norm. I have never encountered the concept of norms for vector spaces over fields other than $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Just to note, there is a way to generalize normed spaces to arbitrary fields, but that requires to generalize absolute values to arbitrary fields. (See my comment above) But of course, most of the time we only work with norms over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

One may consider normed spaces $V$ over fields $K$ with absolute value, such as the $p$-adic fields.  We use the same axioms as with the real or complex case.  This is commonly done in the study of $p$-adic analysis.*
The theorem will be: if $V$ is finite-dimensional and $K$ is complete metric, then there is a unique vector topology for $V$.  Just as in the real and complex cases.  [See if you can prove it!]
However!  When the field is not complete, this may fail.
Example.  Let $K$ be the rational field $\mathbb Q$ with the absolute value $|t|$ inherited from $\mathbb R$.  Then $K$ is not complete.  The two-dimenisonal vector space $V = K^2 = \{(a,b) : a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$ has these two non-equlivalent norms:
$$
\|(a,b)\|_1 = |a|+|b|,\\
\|(a,b)\|_2 = |a+b\sqrt{2}| .
$$

*Robert, Alain M., A course in (p)-adic analysis, Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 198. New York, NY: Springer. xv, 437 p. (2000). ZBL0947.11035.

$\mathbb{K}$ complete metric implies that it has a metric d(x,y) from which we can derived an absolute-value like function: $\forall x \in \mathbb{K},|x|=d(x,0)$ for instance? Sorry if it sounds obvious. Then from "complete" it can be deduced that any closed bounded sub-set contains its suprema which is useful for proving the desired norm equivalence?
